# Is there a VSC Firebase rules extension?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, visual-studio-code, firebase-storage, google-cloud-firestore

Does a `.rules` file format extension exist for Visual Studio Code, with autocomplete and error highlighting?

I would like to configure `.rules` files for the Firebase Realtime Db, Firestore and Cloud-storage.

Comment: I know this is on hold but I would love something like this also. Having to upload your rules to check the syntax is kinda lame.

Comment: Searched for a formatter, too - but only found your topic here. I have installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=toba.vsfire - it's a highlighter, but cannot format code and not check the syntax, but better than nothing ;)

Comment: I've long since forgotten about this question until Paul suggests an edit yesterday. Probably an answer to this question in today's Firebase stack is to use the [Firebase rules emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator) with an extension (there are more choices now).

Comment: check out this vs code extension by Christoph Flick. Specific to Firestore. Provides syntax highlighting, mouse-over info and autocomplete for firestore rules.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChFlick.firecode